# Passing Extras to listView ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons, when you click them, it launches a new listView activity. Before it starts the activity, I make a bundle, putString depending on which button was clicked and putExtras.

In the listView activity, I have two string arrays. I want the ArrayAdapter to getExtras and read the variable so I know which button was pressed to get there and then I'll know which string array to load into the ArrayAdapter.

Here is my idea but the ArrayAdapter doesn't accept the string, even though s = the name of one of the string arrays. Also, I'm not sure if I'm approaching this in the best way.

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = b.getString("TEXT");
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, s));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array adapter takes a list of objects as a third parameter as the documentation on public constructors suggests (Source [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)):

```
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
Constructor
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

So you just need to encapsulate your String in an array (even if you have only one string to display).

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add(s);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, arr));
```

**EDIT**
Ok. Why don't you try a very basic if-else statement? Like:

```
ArrayList<String> arrButton1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arrButton2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arrToChoose;
if(s.equals("button1")) { 
  arrToChoose = arrButton1;
} else if(s.equals("button2")) {
  arrToChoose = arrButton2;
}
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, arrayToChoose));
```

Comment: I tried that but then it only shows my variable. If s = "button1", the only thing that shows up in the listView is button1 if I encapsulate it in an array. I'm trying to load the contents of a string array named button1 in this activity.

Comment: Ok. I hope I understood what problem you are trying to solve. Basically you want to display one array or another depending on whether the user came on this activity by clicking one button or another? See my edit...